# Getting restoration size from a Progress-4gl database

Tags: openedge, progress-db

How can I determine how much storage space on disk a restored database will consume once it has been fully restored? The purpose of this is to ensure that there is enough storage space **before** attempting to restore the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a nice example in the documentation. I'll pull it in here:

**Table 108. Sample PROREST -list output**

```
OpenEdge Release 10.2B1P as of Wed Oct 21 19:01:48 EDT 2009
Area Name: Schema Area
       Size: 11264, Records/Block: 32, Area Number: 6, Cluster Size: 1
Area Name: Info Area
       Size: 1024, Records/Block: 32, Area Number: 7, Cluster Size: 1
Area Name: Customer/Order Area
       Size: 6656, Records/Block: 32, Area Number: 8, Cluster Size: 8
Area Name: Primary Index Area
       Size: 112, Records/Block: 1, Area Number: 9, Cluster Size: 8
Area Name: Customer Index Area
       Size: 256, Records/Block: 1, Area Number: 10, Cluster Size: 64
Area Name: Order Index Area
       Size: 8192, Records/Block: 32, Area Number: 11, Cluster Size: 64
Area Name: Encryption Policy Area
       Size: 20448, Records/Block: 32, Area Number: 12, Cluster Size: 64
Area Name: Audit Area
       Size: 4608, Records/Block: 32, Area Number: 20, Cluster Size: 8
Area Name: Audit Index
       Size: 8704, Records/Block: 32, Area Number: 22, Cluster Size: 8
```

Use the output of PROREST -list to calculate the size of each restored area as follows:

```
area-size = (Size / records-per-block) * database-block-size
```

For example, the size of the restored schema area is:

```
area-size = (Size / records-per-block) * database-block-size
1,441,792 = (11264 / 32) * 4096
```

1441792 will be in bytes so divide it by 1024 (or 1024 * 1024) to get it in kilobytes (or megabytes) etc.

https://documentation.progress.com/output/ua/OpenEdge_latest/index.html#page/dmadm%2Fprorest-utility.html%23

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to do some math, but you can use prorest's -list parameter.

```
prorest -list <restoredb> <backupfile>
```

You'll get a list of each area along with its size and records per block.

```
Area Name: Schema Area
       Size: 12345, Records/Block: 32, Area Number: 6, Cluster Size: 1
```

Divide the size by the records per block, then multiply that by the block size. Do that for each area, add them up, and that should be your database size.